# Semantic UI not working on Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, semantic-ui

I've recently created an angular project using @Angular/cli.

I've installed semantic on the project with the following: `npm install semantic-ui --save`.

After that, I've added the semantic-ui to the .angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.css",
    "styles.css"
]
```

I'm using it into a navbar-component with the following code:

`<button class="ui primary basic button"> Navbar Button! </button>`

Just appears a normal button:

[image]

Why this is happening?

Comment: if you inspect the button element can you see any class?

Comment: Yes, that's what appears: <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="ui primary basic button">Navbar Button!</button>

Comment: I've remade the project and now it seems to work. I think something was broke and semantic got stuck. Now it's working with the same configuration as above.